# MaterialUI Tooltip fade when display= none

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I use materialUI ToolTip for my reactjs project. When block from style `display: block` to style `display: none`, tooltip in that block is fading very fast before disappear.

**Here is my example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/fade-block-tooltip-ui-lb51f

**My problem in codesanbox example**: When I click button "Click me", pink block will `display: none` and tooltip fade very fast before dissapear.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

left all the same as it is now but wrap your tooltip inside the ternary:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fade-block-tooltip-ui-forked-sphxl?file=/src/App.js

UPD: if you need this inside your DOM that better to play with tooltip styles by themself not just add `display: none` to parent because tooltip have an animation for hiding and showing that take some time to hide

Answer (score 0):

I would make it that way (see [LIVE example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fade-block-tooltip-ui-forked-q4dfi?file=/src/App.js) or fragment below).
The whole point of the fix is to combine two blocks into one. In the long run it is easier to scale

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

const style = {
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const onClick = () => setOpen(!open);
  const backgroundColor = open ? "pink" : "blue";
  const btnText = open ? "Clicl me" : "Back";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        My problem: When I click button "Click me", pink block `display: none`
        and tooltip fade before dissapear
      </p>

      <div
        style={{
          ...style,
          backgroundColor
        }}
      >
        <Tooltip title="Tool tip" placement="top">
          <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
            {btnText}
          </button>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Please, let me know if it works or not )

Comment: I want keep blue block, change color is example for 2 block